# Java: Multithreading accessing main thread variables/methods

Tags: java, multithreading, inheritance

I was testing the following code, and I was wondering how come the threads could access the the increment method?

I was thinking this since thread1 and thread2 are objects created from an anonymous class that don't inherit worker class how can they access the increment() method? what is the theory behind it?

```
public class Worker {
    private int count = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        count++;
    }

    public void run() {
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    increment();
                }
            }
        });
        thread1.start();

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    increment();
                }
            }
        });
        thread2.start();

        try {
            thread1.join();
            thread2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Count is: " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Anonymous classes have a reference to their enclosing class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java Language Specification (JLS) states this about [*Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> Inner classes include local (§14.3), anonymous (§15.9.5) and
>   non-static member classes (§8.5).

and [about *Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)

> An inner class C is a direct inner class of a class O if O is the
>   immediately lexically enclosing class of C and the declaration of C
>   does not occur in a static context.

and finally [about *Qualified `this`*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4)

> Any lexically enclosing instance (§8.1.3) can be referred to by
>   explicitly qualifying the keyword `this`.
>
> Let C be the class denoted by `ClassName`. Let n be an integer such that
>   C is the n'th lexically enclosing class of the class in which the
>   qualified this expression appears.
>
> The value of an expression of the form `ClassName.this` is the n'th
>   lexically enclosing instance of `this`.

That's why you can access members of `Worker`.

The call

```
new Runnable()
```

within a `Worker` instance method, creates an inner class for `Worker`. So `Worker` is the 0'th lexically enclosing class of that `Runnable`. With regards to the JLS quotes above, replace `ClassName` with `Worker` and you have access to your method

`Worker.this.increment()`

It's done implicitly by the compiler

Answer (score 4):

Since the `Runnable`s are non-static inner classes , the `Worker.this` is implicitly inherited into the Runnable instances.  So that what is really happening is

```
public void run(){
   Worker.this.increment();
}
```

If the class were static this wouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 1):

An anonymous inner class has access to the enclosing class instance fields and methods. In short, every instance of the inner class keeps a reference to the enclosing class precisely so that it is able to access its fields. If you want more info about inner classes, static classes, etc... check out the Java Tutorials on that topic (Nested Classes) at:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html 
Also, make sure to understand the dangers associated with non-static inner classes, as they can be troublesome and create memory leaks if you hand out references to the inner instance to code outside of the enclosing class.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's a non-static inner class, it captures a reference to the `Worker` instance it is created within. That means you can invoke methods of the worker inside the anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

The "theory" is described in [inner classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3). The practice is, inner class constructors have hidden parameter which refers to outer class instance, and that parameter is saved in a hidden field. This field can be accessed with `Worker.this` construct from inner class methods.

Comment: this means that anonymous classes are always treated as inner classe?

Comment: yes, JLS clearly states that `Inner classes include local, anonymous  and non-static member classes`.